# Conditional 404 response based on inclusion of /node/# in URL

Tags: nodes, uri, blocks

I've been requested by a client to completely block the URLs that contain a `/node/##` after the hostname to prevent these locations from being indexed by search engines.  My issue is that I've already defined a Page Not Found node that gets shown with error 404s.

I've already implemented a modification in the `robots.txt` file to include

```
Disallow: /node/
Disallow: /?q=node/
```

to prevent the web-crawler bots.  However, the URLs are still directly accessible.  So in this case, the client wants two different 404 actions:

- www.clientname.com/testttt -> Drupal renders 404 page
- www.clientname.com/node/897 -> blocked completely without returning Drupal's 404 page.

Does any module allow for this kind of functionality?

Comment: Just an FYI, Drupal will go to some lengths to make these URLs known to the worlds as permalinks / short URLs.  In an ideal world, Globalredirect will solve this issue as it will 301 these to the alias you have defined.

Comment: @MPD, but the client does not want these links redirected.  They want the links blocked completely in a Apache default 403 or 404 page.

Comment: I mainly mention it as this is likely a non-issue.  A spider may get to the site via the node URL, but the 301 will tell it to not index that page.  I do not recall seeing any indexed node URLs on sites where Globalredirect is working properly.  However, if the client requested this...

Answer (score 0):

What about using hook_init in a custom module?

```
function hook_init() {
    // check arg(2) is empty as otherwise will block node edit and delete pages
    if(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 5) == '/node' && arg(2)=='') {
        die(); // to stop completely
        //return drupal_not_found(); // to return 404 page
        //return drupal_access_denied()(); // to return 403 page
    }
}
```

Saying that it would be quicker to block these pages in .htaccess...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a .htaccess addition

```
RewriteRule ^node?$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^node/[0-9]+$ - [F]
```

These throw the 403 errors before Drupal catches them, which is what the client wanted.